# Grabbing alpha numeric characters before the first non alpha numeric

Tags: ms-access

I'm very new to access. I have a data in my column that looks similar to this:

`JONES/KEN`

`SMITH/TAMMY`

`MILLER FRED`

`PICARD.JOHN`

Am I able to grab the letters before the first non-alphanumeric?

So my result would be:

`JONES`

`SMITH`

`MILER`

`PICARD`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a derived table:

```
SELECT Left([Surname],InStr([Surname],[NonAlpha])-1) AS LeftName, 
       MainTable.Surname
FROM MainTable, 
   (SELECT " " As NonAlpha From Table1
    UNION
    SELECT "." As NonAlpha From Table1
    UNION
    SELECT "," As NonAlpha From Table1
    UNION
    SELECT "/" As NonAlpha From Table1)  AS n
WHERE (((MainTable.Surname) Like "*" & [nonalpha] & "*"));
```

Table1 is a scratch table, it does contain records but the query will only
 
return the four assigned rows (,./ )
Maintable is the table with a field Surname, which is the field to be split.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know of a "Word" function that's available in some languages.  I would do it with brute force checking using Instr and then Mid to extract the code.  The construct would be very convoluted to get every kind of character.

I've used the iif function and nested it - this the basic format here:

```
iif (instr (fieldname,"{the character}") > 0, 
     mid(fieldname,1, instr(fieldname,"{the character}")-1, 
     fieldname{or go further into ifs})
```

Using your sample data with Client Name as the field and 3 conditions - space, / and period.  IT does work, but it's ugly - you will have to scroll pretty far to the right to get everything:

```
ShortName: IIf(InStr(1,[client_name]," ")>0,
               mid(client_name,1,InStr(1,[client_name]," ")-1),
               IIf(InStr(1,[client_name],"/")>0,
                   mid(client_name,1,InStr(1,[client_name],"/")-1),
                            IIf(InStr(1,[client_name],".")>0,
                            mid(client_name,1,InStr(1,client_name],".")-1),
                            Client_Name)))
```

Put this in a query based on your table.